# Accessing first row and deleting it instantly

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, t-sql

I have a table where it stores tasks, that need to be executed into a Task Queue table as I am using multi threading to get top 1 from that table and then executing that task. i am getting top 1 record from Task Queue and then I am deleting that record. So for example, if another thread executes before previous thread deletes the task that it picked then both threads may pic same thread. I want know if there is a way to stop other reading from the database until my current thread deletes the thread that it picked?

Comment: You can look into using some sort of table or row lock.  By the way, you don't need to actually do a `DELETE`.  If you are open to soft deletion you could just do an update to mark the task record as completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than doing a `SELECT` followed by a `DELETE`, you may instead perform a `DELETE` with [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause. The `OUTPUT` clause produces a result set but you're now obtaining that result set directly from the `DELETE` and so it's a single atomic operation - two independent executions will not produce the same output row.

Comment: Thanks for your help